# Load javascript file in/before the root svg tag

Tags: php, javascript, xml, svg

I work on a web project where I process XML data with XSLT transformation to this graphically in SVG. The problem that I have is that I need to use some JavaScript for some animations in my SVG graph. I need the JavaScript in/before the root SVG tag to handle the `onload` function.

Any ideas or solutions how to import the JavaScript in/before the root SVG tag to handle the `onload` function?

Comment: Why don't you just do: `$string = $jsString . $svgString`?

Comment: i think that's a ugly solution because if the script is inline you need to have it between the root svg tag and you will get parsing errors( '>' will be '$gt;') in your JavaScript at the client side. i have a other idea but i can post it at the earliest thursday

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to append to the head [0] the script tag pointing to your script or maybe just declaring the script as variable and then appending it too?
or searching to the element SVG position and append it to the parents top

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because of an problem with the path. but a clean solution to load the js from php to the transfromed output is descript in following:

in the transformation file:

```
<xsl:variable name="yourJsAsString" select="default"/>
<script>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
         <![CDATA[
             <xsl:value-of select="$yourJsString"/>
        ]]>
    </xsl:text>
</script>
```

and in the php code:

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsl->setParameter('','$yourJsAsString','your javascript as string');
```

the atvantage is that there are no parsing errors in the transformation output.